# Can 'precedent' mean any preceding event?

Tags: word-usage, contemporary-english

I'm familiar with the legal meaning of *precedent*: an event *A* which sets an example for future similar events *A'*, *A**, etc.

However, *precede* means 'to come before' (e.g. event *A* preceded event *B*, a separate event), and so it seems to me that *precedent* is a natural nominalisation of the verb. Other similar nominalisations include *adjust* to *adjustment* and *oxidise* to *oxidant* (if you can think of any better examples please let me know!).

In sum, would it be correct/reasonable to use *precedent* to describe any event that precedes another - if if they are completely different events?

Answer (score 3):

While "precedent" is an adjective meaning "preceding", the noun form "precedent" is not used for unrelated events: that's not what the word is taken to mean.

For example, while the Big Bang that started our universe preceded the outbreak of World War II, it is not a precedent to that war.

[M-W *precedent*][1]
noun
1: an earlier occurrence of something similar
2a: something done or said that may serve as an example or rule to authorize or justify a subsequent act of the same or an analogous kind  *a verdict that had no precedent*
b: the convention established by such a precedent or by long practice
3: a person or thing that serves as a model

As can be seen from the noun definitions, some comparability between a precedent and an ensuing event must exist.
[1]: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/precedent